# Zend Framework Zend_Dom_Query get Node text

Tags: php, zend-framework

Hi I have a problem getting text out of a result node made by an Zend_Dom_Query

For example I have following html code

```
<h3>
 <img src="wow/img.jpg" />
 <a href="http://wow.com">wow link</a>
```

and I want to get "wow link" how I have to etablish that

The folllowing code I found gets only access on Attributes but is there an likewise way to get access to text?` $testHtml = 'html from above';

```
$dom = new Zend_Dom_Query($testHtml);

// get a element using css child selector
$result = $dom->query('h3 > a');
var_dump($result->current()->getAttribute('href'));
```

Hope there are Ideas.

Thx in advance

Ben`

Answer (score 3):

Use `textContent` property of the resulting `DOMElement` object:

```
$dom = new Zend_Dom_Query($testHtml);

$result = $dom->query('h3 > a');
var_dump( $result->current()->textContent );
```

Comment: How do you write those changes back to the `Zend_Dom_Query` object?

Comment: @Sonny not sure what you mean. There're no changes made to the `Zend_Dom_Query` object, there's merely getting a value.

Comment: So I discovered on the post I created: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914643/writing-changes-back-to-a-zend-dom-query-object

Answer (score 0):

Iam using

```
$dom = new Zend_Dom_Query($xhtml);
$results = $dom->query('h3 > a');

foreach ($results as $result) {
   echo $result->nodeValue;
}
```

Works fine for me with ZF 1.10.x