# Writing Changes Back to a Zend Dom Query Object

Tags: php, zend-framework, dom

I want to loop through images in an HTML document and set the width/height if they don't exist.

Here's a minimal piece of working code:

```
$content = '<img src="example.gif" />';
$dom = new Zend_Dom_Query($content);
$imgs = $dom->query('img');
foreach ($imgs as $img) {
    $width = (int) $img->getAttribute('width');
    $height = (int) $img->getAttribute('height');
    if ((0 == $width) && (0 == $height)) {
        $img->setAttribute('width', 100));
        $img->setAttribute('height', 100);
    }
}
$content = $dom->getDocument();
```

The `setAttribute()` calls set the values, and I've verified that by echoing the values.  The problem is that the `DOMElement` is not getting written back to the `Zend_Dom_Query` object.  The `$content` variable is unchanged at the end.

---

**SOLUTION**: [cbuckley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/283078/cbuckley) gets the credit, but here is my final working code:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($content);
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('img') as $img) {
    if ((list($width, $height) = getimagesize($img->getAttribute('src')))
            && (0 === (int) $img->getAttribute('width'))
            && (0 === (int) $img->getAttribute('height'))) {
        $img->setAttribute('width', $width);
        $img->setAttribute('height', $height);
    }
}
$content = $doc->saveHTML();
```

Doing it with `Zend_Dom_Query`:

```
$dom = new Zend_Dom_Query($content);
$imgs = $dom->query('img');
foreach ($imgs as $img) {
    if ((list($width, $height) = getimagesize($img->getAttribute('src')))
            && (0 === (int) $img->getAttribute('width'))
            && (0 === (int) $img->getAttribute('height'))) {
        $img->setAttribute('width', $width);
        $img->setAttribute('height', $height);
    }
}
$content = $imgs->getDocument()->saveHTML();
```

Comment: I'd guess that your if statement is getting passed over as `FALSE` - Maybe because the original string is lacking the attributes you are looking for. I'd recommend also testing `$width` and `$height` for `NULL`.

Comment: That's not the issue.  I can echo `$img->getAttribute('width')` after setting it, and the value is there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Zend_Dom_Query object holds your content string as its "document". The document you seek is in another object; it's returned in the Zend_Dom_Query_Result object `$imgs`, so use `$imgs->getDocument()` instead.

You could also do it with direct DOM manipulation:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXml($content);

foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('img') as $img) {
    $width  = (int) $img->getAttribute('width');
    $height = (int) $img->getAttribute('height');

    if (0 === $width && 0 === $height) {
        $img->setAttribute('width',  '100');
        $img->setAttribute('height', '100');
    }
}

$content = $doc->saveXML();
```